# Closure: How can I tactfully ask someone to reply more promptly?

Tags: discussion

One of the closers [commented](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/12373/how-can-i-tactfully-ask-someone-to-reply-more-promptly?noredirect=1#comment50792_12373):

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic **[1.] because this site isn't an e-mail writing service as you've already been explained countless times.** **[2.] Also, please stop reposting your old, deleted questions without improvements.**

1. I didn't intend to ask for help with writing emails. I yearn to know how to solve the difficulty, but sorry if my writing is too fuzzy. Is including possible emails unhelpful? I can remove them, and let the community advise how to proceed?
2. This bold sentence looks unfair. I'm not reposting old deleted questions, and certainly not without improvements.

Answer (score 6):

As written the question looks like you're wanting help drafting an email. Drafting an email and other questions effectively asking "What do I say?" are off topic.

Looking at your question history you've asked many questions all about getting a faster response to some sort of request in an office setting. They all look like duplicates to me and should probably be closed. I think the only reason that this question wasn't closed as one was because it was also off topic so it was easier to close it as that than search through the archive to find the questions that it duplicates.

Without a direct link I can't see any questions you may have deleted I cannot comment on whether you are reposting deleted questions. But you are definitely reposting duplicates of questions you have already asked.

Answer (score 3):

1. I'm done pointing out improvements, just to never see them executed (properly). If the rest of the community want to frustrate themselves, I'm going to let them answer your first point.
2. I wrote that comment. I can't find the question in question (because I no longer hold a link to it, I can only view deleted posts if there's a link somewhere), but you DID ask about holding replies before. The fact that I can't find it, means it was probably closed and deleted, just like a lot of your questions.

Maybe you didn't repost an exact duplicate, but another version of the same tale of woe is just as bad. Be advised that you already have A LOT of questions on your profile (excluding the deleted ones that I can no longer see because I don't have the links to them) asking about either how to get faster e-mail replies or deterring someone's questions/deflecting remarks, and that writing duplicate questions is not a good idea either.

Comment: 'I'm done pointing out improvements, just to never see them executed (properly).' 3. What is wrong with this current post? Let us overlook the others to simplify. 4. I believe that I authorized anyone to edit my posts for improvement? You should feel free to!

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal edits are largely for improving readability, adjusting tags and improved formatting. it is NOT for people to post low quality questions and have them saved by strangers putting in a lot more effort than you